# Does HtmlUnit load images when it browses page?

Tags: java, image, htmlunit

as above.
Does it load images?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By default: no.

1. You have to use htmlImage.[getImageReader()](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlImage.html#getImageReader%28%29)
2. Or, you can use htmlPage.[save()](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#save%28java.io.File%29)

**Update: as of 2.25**, you can use:

```
webClient.getOptions().setDownloadImages(true);
```